# fetching data from inner array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

my nested array structure like this

```
[{"orderid":123 "ex1"{"status":10},"ex2"{"status":10}},{"orderid":456"ex1"{"status":20}}]
```

how to fetch data from inner array(inner array means ex1,ex2) in javascript.please help me.i am new to javascript.

Comment: "_my nested array structure_" is a total mess...

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root array does not contain another array but rather objects, which are here displayed in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) (although it currently isn't syntaxicaly correct, which I will assume comes from copy/paste mistakes).

In the following, I will assume this is the data you're working with :

```
[{"orderid":123, "ex1":{"status":10},"ex2":{"status":10}},{"orderid":456,"ex1":{"status":20}}]
```

Which could be formatted for better readability :

```
[
  {
    "orderid": 123,
    "ex1": {
      "status": 20
    },
    "ex2": {
      "status": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "orderid":456,
    "ex1":{
      "status":20
    }
  }
]
```

Once you have accessed the object through indexing of the array, you can access its properties by their name.

```
var firstObject = myArray[0];
var firstObjectEx1 = firstObject.ex1;
var firstObjectEx1Status = firstObjectEx1.status;
```

Or in a single line :

```
myArray[0].ex1.status
```

Comment: @aaraon ...yeah..myarray[0].ex1.status works...i need to do it dynamically,means inside loop.. for(i=0:i<n;i++){myArray[0].ex+i.status}..is it possible??

Comment: well change the `[0]` part with indexing on an incremented var; `myArray[i]` in your example

Comment: Then use a loop. like
for(int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
    //dostuff with myarray[i].ex1.status;
}

Comment: This goes out of the scope of the question, and I feel like you would benefit from following a JS tutorial. `ex` does not refer to anything previously stated. `ex1` is an object, appending a value to it has no sense. However you could set another propery on it if that's what you want : `myArray[i].ex1.newProperty= newValue;`